# Collect Users Data - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

I'm working on a personal website project.
I want to make my users understand their personal data on facebook, twitter etc ...

To do this, I will use Omniauth with the different API's.

But I have no idea what database I should use to store the data.
I'm actually using PostgreSQL on my rails app.

Answer (score -1):

You can use any database, mysql, postgresql, sqlite etc. If you know that your data has some kind of schema, you can use any of these. If you want your app to save any kind of data, you can use any noSQL database like [mongodb with mongoid](https://gorails.com/guides/setting-up-rails-4-with-mongodb-and-mongoid) or you can use [hstore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/hstore.html) feature of postgresql.